# Why is vb.net so fast?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I wrote the same console application in several languages. The application asks the user for a number and counts from 1 to that number, printing each number on a separate line in the console. I actually expected vb.net to come worst out of the programming languages, what makes me curious is that it didn't, it's actually the fastest.

VB.Net - Run through the VS debugger:

```
Sub Main()
    Console.Write("Give me a number, any number: ")

    For i = 1 To CInt(Console.ReadLine)
        Console.WriteLine(i)
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

C++ - Run through the VS debugger (About 5x slower than VB):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Give me a number, any number: ";

int number; cin >> number;
cout << '\n';

for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) cout << i << '\n';

while (true) {}
}
```

Haskell - Compiled and run from the console (Only slightly slower than VB):

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad 

main = do
    putStr "Give me a number, any number: "
    hFlush stdout

    input <- getLine
    mapM print [1..read input]

    return 0
```

Javascript - Run through firebug in firefox (A lot slower than VB):

```
for (i = 0; i<100000; i++){ console.log(i); }
```

Befunge - Run [through this](http://www.quirkster.com/iano/js/befunge.html) website using chrome/javascript (faster than firefox, but still slower than vb)

```
&1-0>1+:.134*+,\:#v_@
    ^          \-1<
```

So simply, what makes the vb solution faster than the other languages?

Comment: 1. What are your benchmark results? 2. Why not make all the samples do the same thing? 3. You know you're benchmarking the console writes, right, rather than looping and math?

Comment: Totally agree. Printing out the results is the slowest thing in this code. Plus, I think you should try it in Release not Debug mode. The c++ executable in debug contains additional information and might be slower.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta Well, I actually just wanted to visually see how much faster c++ where than vb, so I just sort of wrote it as fast and short as I could. When c++, to my surprice was alot slower than vb I just wrote the same program in a few other languages, whereas Haskell because they brag about they're compiler. I tested them agains eachother by giving the languages the same number and running them simuntainlusly several times.

Comment: @user2468852 It shouldn't really matter as they're all printing, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you expect VB.NET to be the slowest? Once compiled, a VB.NET program is a CIL program, the same as a c# program. And after the .NET JIT Compiler compiles it, it is compiled to native code, quite optimized. Javascript is an interpreted language, and firebug is an interpreter/debugger, which slows down the code so you may trace debug information. I expect the same to be true with the C++ debugger. Do you get slower results when you run the c++ program withOUT the debugger?

Answer (score -1):

c++ is slower when asked to optimize and running under Release, with no debugger attached, reason, c++ is not a Cached language, it has to work out everything every single step. compared to CIL .Net Framework Realises that it is the same operation and works out the difference. Plus c++ is an old language.

Comment: It's hard to find any parts of this answer that are in any way related to reality.